# Django Debug Toolbar: Log section cleared every time a page is loaded

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I'm experimenting with Django Debug Toolbar, everything works fine except I can't see "historic" Log Entries in the log Panel.

Here's an example of the Django views file, used for testing purposes

```
from django.shortcuts import render

#logging
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    logger.debug('Home view called')
    return render(request, 'main/home.html')

def news(request):
    logger.debug('News view called')
    logger.debug('News view called 2nd time')
    return render(request, 'main/news.html', {'content': "That's some kind of news"})
```

If I call the home page, in the log panel I can see just:

```
Home view called
```

Then If I call the news page, in the log panel I can see just:

```
News view called
News view called 2nd time
```

Every time I call 'Home' or 'News' the Log is cleared

Is there a way to instruct Django Toolbar to keep/show previous entries?
Am I missing something?

Thank you